# IOS: change UIImageView with tag value

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, tags, uiimageview

I have 20 UIImageView and i want change their image; but I don't want to create 20 IBOutlet, and I want to use tag value to change the image; I set the tag value in interface builder and after? If I want to change image at Imageview number 15? How can I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use tags you can identify your tagged view (UIImageView is a subclass of UIView, which has the tag attribute) like this:

```
- (UIView *)viewWithTag:(NSInteger)tag
```

So if you call this method on your superview (which all the UIImageViews reside in), you should do it like this:

```
UIImageView *myImageView = (UIImageView *)[myAwesomeSuperview viewWithTag:15];
```

([Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) I found using Google).

P.S: if you think it is too much work to add 20 IBOutlets, I recommend you create the UIImageViews programmatically as well. This way you will not need a xib file at all, write a small piece of code and have better maintenance with less effort.

Comment: You might want to type cast it since viewWithTag returns UIView..UIImageView *myImageView = (UIImageView*)[myAwesomeSuperview viewWithTag:15];

Answer (score 17):

```
UIImageView *imageView=(UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:*givetag*];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nameof yourimage"]];
```

Answer (score 2):

SWIFT, April 2015:

```
func createUIImageViews()
{
    for i in 0...99
    {
        var imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(CGFloat(0), CGFloat(0), CGFloat(100), CGFloat(100)))
        imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        imageView.tag = i
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "onImageViewTap:"))

        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
    }
}



func onImageViewTap(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    println("TAP: \(sender.view!.tag)")
}
```